# How to read Visio Binary Format (.vsd)

Tags: c++, parsing, visio

I am building a program to parse .vsd file.

But I don't know where to find link introduce Visio Binary Format (.vsd) specs.

Answer (score 2):

Visio binary format (VSD) is a proprietary format (means - there is no documentation publicly available)

I have seen libvisio package from LibreOffice which seems to be capable of doing this, but may need to dig into sources: https://github.com/LibreOffice/libvisio